# spring-cloud-sleuth with opentracing

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using the latest milestone of spring-cloud-sleuth and I can't seem to get traces emitted through opentracing. I have a `Tracer` bean defined and spring boot seems to acknowledge that, but no traces are being emitted.

Is there a way to check if spring-cloud-sleuth is aware of the Tracer bean?

***update***

I did see the merged documentation and have a `Tracer` instance on the bean, as defined below:

```
@Bean(name = "tracer")
@Primary
public Tracer lightstepTracer() throws MalformedURLException {
    Options opt = lightstepOptionsBuilder.build();
    log.info("Instantiating LightStep JRETracer.");
    return new JRETracer(opt);
}
```

I'm not explicitly importing the OpenTracing APIs, because the LightStep tracer pulls that in transitively, but I can try doing that.

I've also explicitly enabled OpenTracing support in my application.yml file.

```
sleuth:
  opentracing:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Can you not name the bean tracer and try again? If that doesn't work then please upload a sample that replicates the issue

Comment: I'll try to put together a sample. The bean is named `tracer`, per the `@Bean(name = "tracer")` annotation.

Comment: I asked you not to name it tracer and try again

Comment: Ah, I read that differently. I can try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the latest snapshot documentation (or milestone) and you search for the word OpenTracing, you would get your answer. It's here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_opentracing

> Spring Cloud Sleuth is compatible with OpenTracing. If you have OpenTracing on the classpath, we automatically register the OpenTracing Tracer bean. If you wish to disable this, set `spring.sleuth.opentracing.enabled` to false

So it's enough to just have OpenTracing on the classpath and Sleuth will work out of the box